# Empty Page!! Error when trying to generate a box file with tesseract

Tags: image-processing, ocr, tesseract

I'm trying to train tesseract on a custom font.

When try to generate a training file with: `tesseract lang.font-name.exp0.tif lang.font-name.exp0.box nobatch box.train` I get the error `Empty page!!`

I've been following [this](https://michaeljaylissner.com/posts/2012/02/11/adding-new-fonts-to-tesseract-3-ocr-engine/) guide. I've created my tif file, loaded it into `jTessBoxEditor` and manually added the boxes as none were auto populated.

I'm under the impression all I need is the tif file and the box file, those get fed in the `box.train` command and out comes a `tf` file.

What does `Empty Page!!` mean and how do I fix it?

[image]

Comment: Do you know difference between `page` and `line`?

Comment: In reference to psm modes? yes, training, no.

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem. Here is the solution I found: The problem is that tesseract has problems with creating boxes when there is not enough space around the image. Increase the white space around your input and it should work.